# Как получить завтрашнюю дату python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Как получить завтрашнюю дату в формате dd.mm ?

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

tomorrow_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1).strftime("%d.%m")
```

Пробовал так, но ловлю ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Как исправить?

Comment: tomorrow_date = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d.%m")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ не совсем по теме, но лично я использую для работы со временем не встроенный datetime, а сторонний pendulum, где все более понятно (я бы сказал, на интуитивном уровне).

```py
import pendulum

tomorrow = pendulum.tomorrow('Europe/Moscow').format('DD.MM')
```

Поэтому, если нет каких-либо ограничений, можно смело использовать и эту библиотеку

Answer (score 2):

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

print(tomorrow.strftime('%d.%m'))
```